# WordPress get_users() by role only returning those that have the role, plus another

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a list of users using get_users() the have a certain role. But for some reason, it's only returning the users that have the role I'm looking for, plus one more role assigned to them. But it's not returning the users are assigned only the role I'm looking for.

I've also used wp_user_query, with the same result

```
$role = 'pmpro_role_1';

$args = array(
    'role' => $role,
    'fields' => array('ID', 'user_email', 'display_name')
);

$raw = get_users( $args );

foreach ( $raw as $user ){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
foreach($users as $user_id){
        print_r(get_user_meta ( $user_id->ID));
}
```

Get user by ID

Answer (score 0):

replace $raw = get_users( $args ); by $raw = get_user_by( $args ); where $args = $id